# C++ Invalid Conversion

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-errors

The following code produces the compilation error, `invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'`. Both `ptrInputFileName` and `ptrFileName` are both declared as `const char*`.  Any suggestions on how to get this to compile? Thank you.

```
TextInputBuffer::TextInputBuffer(const char *ptrInputFileName)
    : ptrFileName(new char[strlen(ptrInputFileName) + 1])
{
    //--Copy the file name.
    std::strcpy(ptrFileName, ptrInputFileName);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strcpy` takes the the destination as non-const pointer `char*` and `ptrFileName` is `const char*`. No implicit conversion possible and I wouldn't recommend an explicit conversion. Just make `ptrFileName` non-const.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously, you can't copy into a something pointed to by  a const * - remove the const, and if that cause problems calling the constructor, you are doing something semantically invalid.

Also, your use of pseudo-hungarian makes the code difficult to read. Lose the `ptr` prefixes, and make the names shorter.

Comment: The negative value of these name prefixes needs to be more widely recognized.

Comment: It's much easier to see if you need to print ptr or *ptr in a huge file if you have prefixes. If you declare a pointer to a, which contains 5, there is a big difference in printing *ptr, which prints 5, and printing ptr, which prints 0xbce8f4.

Comment: @duns No, it isn't. Hungarian was a bad idea when it was invented, and it has no place in C++. Don't use it.

Comment: @Neil: Do you feel the same way about Apps Hungarian as you do about Systems Hungarian?

Comment: @Bill I like my variables to have names like `root`, `path` and `pos` (picked at random from some source of mine), if that answers the question. The idea of encoding type in a variable name is so obviously broken I'm surprised it ever got established in the first place.

Comment: @Neil: For example, if you had a position relative to the window and a position relative to the desktop, would you use a convention like `winPos` and `deskPos`, or would you do something like `pos1` and `pos2`?  If the former, then it's Apps Hungarian.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I believe you misunderstood Bill.  "Apps" vs "Systems" is the difference between unsafe_user_input and str_user_input.  "Unsafe" or "row" (instead of "col") is "the type" (cf. "a category") of variables, but it was misunderstood to correspond with the typesystem of the language.  The misunderstanding was widely promulgated and is what most people know. :(

Comment: @Bill No it isn't - it's normal naming convention, that programmers have been using since the year dot. Do you really think people only used names like pos1 and pos2 before hungarian was invented!

Comment: @Neil: I think some people describe the logical use of a variable better than others.  If you're in favor of  encoding your use into the name of the variable then you're in favor of Apps Hungarian.

Comment: @Bill I'm in favour of not calling it that! When I was writing code 30 years ago that looked like that, years before anyone had heard of Charles Simonyi, was I writing "apps hungarian"? No, I wasn't!

Comment: @Neil: People were probably acquiring resources in a constructor and releasing them in a destructor before someone decided to call it RAII... it's still useful to have these terms so that we each can know what the other is talking about.

Comment: @dunsmoreb:  Even MicroSoft, where Hungarian was invented, now discourages the use of Hungarian notation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Use std::string.

```
struct TextInputBuffer {
  TextInputBuffer(const char *filename)
  : _filename(filename)
  {}

  // Explicit delete not even required as it would have been
  // when you used new.

private:
  std::string _filename;
};
```